# Milo: get IP of client

Tags: opc-ua, milo

Is there a way to get a Clients IP in Context of a write?
I want to get the IP of an Client that writes to my Milo-OPCUA-Server, so I can handle these writes differently based on the Clients IP (local Clients should be able to write directly on the Server, whilst other writes should get forwarded to another Server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is not part of any official API right now, so it almost certainly will break in the future, but:

With the `OperationContext` you get when implementing `AttributeManager#write(WriteContext, List<WriteValue>)`:

```
context.getSession().ifPresent(session -> {
    UaStackServer stackServer = context.getServer().getServer();

    if (stackServer instanceof UaTcpStackServer) {
        ServerSecureChannel secureChannel = ((UaTcpStackServer) stackServer)
            .getSecureChannel(session.getSecureChannelId());

        Channel channel = secureChannel.attr(UaTcpStackServer.BoundChannelKey).get();

        SocketAddress remoteAddress = channel.remoteAddress();
    }
});
```

---

I'll have to add some official API to do this, probably something hanging off the `Session` object.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that'll do it for now. Although i'd be great if you could bring this to the `Session`-Object